# Lexicographical sort algorithm using C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, algorithm

I am struggling to write a sorting algorithm that can sort characters in a word lexicographically (alphabetically) as follows

lexicographical sort of the word :- **Contamination**

> lexicographically
>   Sorted Text               Index
>   ------------------         ----------
>   amination                      0
>   ation                                         1
>   contamination                    2
>   ination                                      3
>   ion                                               4
>   mination                                  5
>   n                                                   6
>   nation                                      7
>   ntamination                         8
>   on                                                9
>   ontamination                     10
>   tamination                            11
>   tion                                           12

Could anyone please help write a pseudo code / or an implementation in C# or VB.NET  of how I can do a lexicographical sort of the word above?

Comment: So you need to know how to lexicographically sort the documents given the example lexicographically sorted text? (e.g. not assuming a known alphabet?).

Comment: What code have you got already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string str = "contamination";
IEnumerable<string> sortedSubstrings =
    Enumerable.Range(0, str.Length)
              .Select(i => str.Substring(i))
              .OrderBy(s => s);
```

Answer (score 6):

You could simply do:

```
var parts = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
    parts.Add(word.Substring(i));

parts.Sort();
```

The output should be as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this:

```
Array.Sort(yourCollection);
```

Answer (score 0):

The default C# sort function sorts strings lexicographically, so in your case:

```
YourList.Sort();
```

should do the trick, if you want to customize the sorting function, you can pass a function to the Sort method:

```
YourList.Sort((a, b) => SomeSortingFunction(a,b));
```

When you write SomeSortingFunction make sure it returns a negative value if a is before b, a positive value if a is after b and zero if they are equal.